# Ошибка с десериализации XML

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация, десериализация

Есть класс который я сперва сериализую в xml (удачно), а потом хочу десериализовать.

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ApiData")]
    public class ApiData
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ResponseCount")]
        public int ResponseCount { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "KosherName")]
        public string KosherName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "RepostCount")]
        public int RepostCount { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "CommentCount")]
        public int CommentCount { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ArrayOfApiData")]
    public class ArrayOfApiData
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ApiData")]
        public List<ApiData> ApiData { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsi { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsd", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsd { get; set; }
    }

}


 public static void SerializeObject<T>(T serializableObject, string fileName)
        {
            if (serializableObject == null) { return; }

            try
            {
                XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializableObject.GetType());
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(stream, serializableObject);
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    xmlDocument.Load(stream);
                    xmlDocument.Save(fileName);
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log exception here
            }
        }

        public static T DeSerializeObject<T>(string fileName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) { return default(T); }

            T objectOut = default(T);

            try
            {
                string attributeXml = string.Empty;

                XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDocument.Load(fileName);
                string xmlString = xmlDocument.OuterXml;

                using (StringReader read = new StringReader(xmlString))
                {
                    Type outType = typeof(T);

                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(outType);
                    using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(read))
                    {
                        objectOut = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                        reader.Close();
                    }

                    read.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log exception here
            }

            return objectOut;
        }
```

Вот примерное содержимое файла xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArrayOfApiData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ApiData>
    <ResponseCount>0</ResponseCount>
    <Id>club62195050</Id>
    <KosherName>-62195050</KosherName>
    <RepostCount>0</RepostCount>
    <CommentCount>1</CommentCount>
  </ApiData>
```

Когда я хочу этот файл десериализовать, он у меня ругается на

```
Message = "В документе XML (1, 23) присутствует ошибка."
```

Чем то ему описание версии xml не нравится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код работает. Обратите внимания на тип `ArrayOfApiData` при вызове:

```
var arr = DeSerializeObject<ArrayOfApiData>("data.xml");
```

Вы можете избавится от определения полей `Xsi` и `Xsd` в классе `ArrayOfApiData`:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ArrayOfApiData")]
public class ArrayOfApiData
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ApiData")]
    public List<ApiData> ApiData { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Ваш код методов можно записать короче:

```
public static void SerializeObject<T>(T serializableObject, string fileName)
{
    if (serializableObject == null) { return; }

    using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(fs, serializableObject);
    }
}

public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string fileName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName)) { return default (T); }

    using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fs);
    }
}
```

Сделаны следующие изменения:

1. Убраны лишние вызовы `XmlDocument`, `MemoryStream` и тд.
2. `serializableObject.GetType()` заменен на `typeof(T)`.
3. Удалены оба блока `try-catch`
4. Обработка параметров методов не изменилась, но она требует переработки...

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код, в том виде, в котором он приведен в вопросе, работает. В нем, правда, XML зачем-то прогоняется через `XmlDocument` вместо прямой записи в файл, но на результат это не влияет. Т.е. код вида

```
SerializeObject(obj, @"some.xml");
DeSerializeObject<ArrayOfApiData>(@"some.xml");
```

возвращает копию оригинального объекта. Вот только XML при этом отличается от приведенного в примере. Он начинается с

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Т.е. тот XML, который у вас приведен - это не результат работы кода из вопроса. И он вполне может быть битым. Например, у него может быть неправильный BOM - первые байты файла, задающие формат. При несоответствии из кодировке, указанной в `<?xml>`, чтение документа упадет именно с такой ошибкой.

Уберите лишний код из своего сериализатора и десериализатора, это скорее всего уберет ошибку:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializableObject.GetType());
using (var stream = File.Create(fileName))
{
    serializer.Serialize(stream, serializableObject);
}

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
{
    return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
}
```